# understanding recursive decimal to binary code?

Tags: c, recursion, binary, decimal

I'm working on a program that can convert number to its binary form.

With help, I was able to get this, and it seems to work but I just don't understand how. I guess the best way to do this is to try to explain how I think this is working and someone can correct me.

I have a function that has an if statement that says if n divided by 2 isn't equal to 0 then divide n by 2. Then it prints the remainder if n /2 so either 1 or 0.

The main function just runs the function with whatever number I give it, in this case 456.

But how does the program know to run the function multiple times to get the entire binary form?

I feel like this isn't that complicated but I'm not getting it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ConvertToBinary(int n)
{
    if (n / 2 != 0) {
        ConvertToBinary(n / 2);
    }
    printf("%d", n % 2);
}

int main (){
    ConvertToBinary (456);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack overflow is no code review or tutorial site.

Comment: "Then it prints the remainder if n /2 so either 1 or 0"  or `-1` if `n_original < 0`.

Answer (score 3):

The function `ConvertToBinary` is recursive, meaning it calls itself.  At some point the function needs to know when to stop calling itself.  This is called the base case.

On the first call to this function, n=456.  In this case `n/2 != 0` is true, so the function calls itself, this time with 228.  It keeps calling itself until it gets passed a value where `n/2 != 0` is false, which is the base case.  The innermost call to the function then prints `n % 2` and returns.  The next innermost call also prints `n % 2` for its value of `n`, and so on up the call stack.

So the function calls look something like this:

```
ConvertToBinary(456)
    ConvertToBinary(456/2=228)
        ConvertToBinary(228/2=114)
            ConvertToBinary(114/2=57)
                ConvertToBinary(57/2=28)
                    ConvertToBinary(28/2=14)
                        ConvertToBinary(14/2=7)
                            ConvertToBinary(7/2=3)
                                ConvertToBinary(3/2=1)
                                    print 1%2=1
                                print 3%2=1
                            print 7%2=1
                        print 14%2=0
                    print 28%2=0
                print 57%2=1
            print 114%2=0
        print 228%2=0
    print 456%2=0
```

Result:

```
111001000
```

Answer (score 1):

Step through it line by line on a piece of lined paper.  Use indention as you make recursive calls, then unindent as you return.  Place the output in the right column of your paper.

I would start with simple numbers like 1, 4, 7, 10, then try 456.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer here but I'll try and explain as best I can. This is an example of recursion (Google that) which is a powerful tool for solving certain kinds of problems. The trick is that the method calls itself, so tracing it through (with a smaller example):

1st call 
    n = 13
    call ConvertToBinary with 13 / 2 = 6

2nd call
    n = 6;
    call ConvertToBinary with 6 / 2 = 3

3rd call
    n = 3
    call ConvertToBinary with 3 / 2 = 1

4th call
    n = 1
    1 / 2 = 0 so continue through!
    print 1 % 2 = 1
    method exits and returns to the 3rd call

3rd call again
    print 3 % 2 = 1
    method exits and returns to the 2nd call

2nd call again
    print 6 % 2 = 0
    method exits and returns to the 1st call

1st call again
    print 13 % 2 = 1
    and done!

Now we have 1101 which is 13 in binary,

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ConvertToBinary(int n)
{

 // is the number passed in 2 or greater? If so, print out the smaller binary digits first. 
 if (n / 2 != 0) {  

 // this is a recursive call. It won't return until all the smaller binary digits have been printed. 
 ConvertToBinary(n / 2);
}

 // all the smaller digits have been printed, time to print out the current binary digit. 
 printf("%d", n % 2);
}

int main (){
ConvertToBinary (456);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Detail: "is the number passed in 2 or greater?" really should be "is the absolute value of the number passed in 2 or greater?" as `n` may have a negative value.

Comment: The program will not work with negative values. What is -5%2 ?

Comment: The function will "work" with `ConvertToBinary(-5)` producing the output "-10-1", certainly not desirable.   `-5%2` --> `-1`.