# any program Decimal to Binary by recursion

Tags: c, recursion, binary, decimal

[image]

I have to write a recurcive function without `for` or `while` 
that prints all binary numbers from 0 to a given integer:

e.g. if the integer was `7` output is this:

> (000)
>   (001)
>   (010)
>   (011)
>   (100)
>   (101)
>   (110)
>   (111)

Here's the code I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function declaration */
int print_binary_number(int decimalNo,int count,int arr[]);

int main ()
{
    int a;

    printf("\nPlease enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    print_binary_number(a,0,0);
    return 0;
}

int print_binary_number(int decimalNo,int count,int arr[])
{
    int binaryNo,remainder,factor = 1,c;

    if (decimalNo == 0) {
        return 0;
        printf("000");
    }

    if(decimalNo != 0){

        remainder = decimalNo % 2;
        arr[count]=remainder;
        binaryNo = (binaryNo + (remainder * factor));
        factor = factor * 10;

        print_binary_number(decimalNo - 1,count,arr);
        c=1+print_binary_number(decimalNo / 2,count++,arr);

    }
    printf("%d",arr[count]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why are you tagging C# and C? Choose a language.

Comment: i know both languages and i need help in c or c#, i wrote an program but it doesnt work ::

Comment: Post the code that doesn't work.

Comment: i edit the post

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the method from main?

Comment: `   int main ()
{

  int a;
 printf("\nPlease enter an integer:\n");
 scanf("%d",&a);
 print_binary_number(a,0,0);
 return 0;
}`

Comment: thank_u michael for trying understand me

Comment: your welcome. I'll try to help. I'll send you a comment or post an answer if I can come up with something.

Comment: It seems like this question is about C, since `printf` is a C function and I see nothing indicating C# whatsoever. Perhaps you meant C++?

Comment: it is about c but any help by c# its good i wrote what the recusion function well do, if you can help me thank you abion47

Comment: @majdnassar you do it waaay too complicated, untangling all of it would be a bit tedious. You may look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33204772/understanding-recursive-decimal-to-binary-code for a much simpler approach, although a bit *too* simple (see the comments there).

Comment: @deamentiaemundi this program print the binary number to any integer number but my program must print all numbers from 0 to the scanned number by binary ( if i entered 7 the program must print all numbers between 0 to 7 by binary format ..thank you for trying

Comment: What exactly is your qustion? Doesn´t the code you´ve posted work as you expected? What results do you get?

Comment: @majdnassar that program prints *one* number, just write another recursive function incrementing from `0` to `n` and call the recursive conversion function each time. Or shorter: call that recursive function recursively.

Comment: i tried a lot but it doesnt work>>i can write print binary number to any integer but they request to print all number between 0 to the integer be binary format...it doesnt work .. @HimBromBeere

Comment: @deamentiaemundi it must be recursive function

Comment: Downvoting because of the image: having it as pic instead of text looks just lazy.

Comment: In case you were curious, this is how you do it in C# (it's a bit easier): https://dotnetfiddle.net/AqBdKG

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This example covers your following needs:

- Recursion
- Display binary numbers in range
- You can specify how many bits to display

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_binary_numbers(int from, int to, int bits);
void print_binary(int n, int bits);

int main (void){
    int n;
    printf("Please enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    print_binary_numbers(0, n, 8);
    return 0;
}

/**
 * @param bits Controls the number of displayed bits.
 */
void print_binary(int n, int bits) {
    while (--bits >= 0){
        printf("%s", n & (1 << bits) ? "1" : "0");
    }
}

void print_binary_numbers(int from, int to, int bits) {
    print_binary(from, bits);
    printf("\n");
    if (from < to) {
        print_binary_numbers(from + 1, to, bits);
    }
}
```

Comment: it must a recurcive function without while .. thank you for trying

Comment: Recursion is in the first example

Comment: `Convert.ToString` probably uses a loop under the covers - may not be allowed??

Comment: Well, internally it uses an extern method. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/parsenumbers.cs,9d6624da44b02e1f

Comment: I has added detailed implementation (recursive / cyclic approach)

Comment: That's clearly not C!

Comment: @Olaf Firstly, OP needs to decide what he wants. He was asked the code for C or C#. I posted this answer.

Comment: @Olaf I has added implementation using C language

Comment: Any reason you left the C# stuff? The question is not about C#, but C, so it is nonsense and potentially missleading to future readers. If a question is unclear, you should use a comment to request clarification. If you don't have the reps to comment, just wait, someone will. However, we are not a coding service. You don't answer the question (what **is** the question?) and your code invokes undefined behaviour for certain constellations. It also uses unnecessary casts. That's what I found by a short peek; not going to dig deeper.

Comment: The answer was edited. @Olaf Thanks for your reply. I totally agree with you.

Answer (score -1):

By C /* compile with -O2 option */

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_binary_number(int decimalNo, int width, char arr[]);

int main (void){
    int a;
    char arr[32] = {0};

    printf("\nPlease enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    int width = 0;
    for(unsigned c = a; c; c >>= 1)
        ++width;
    print_binary_number(a, width, arr);
    return 0;
}

void print_binary_number(int decimalNo, int width, char arr[]){
    for(int i = width-1; i>=0; --i)
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    if(!decimalNo)
        return ;
    for(int i = 0, carry = 1, c; carry; ++i, carry = c){
        c = arr[i] & carry;
        arr[i] ^= carry;
    }
    print_binary_number(decimalNo-1, width, arr);
}
```

Comment: pos += sprintf(&tmp[pos], "%d", (n & ((int)1<<bits)) ? 1 : 0);  what this do?

Comment: @majdnassar Why are you asking me?